# How do you compose functions in PureScript?

Tags: functional-programming, purescript, function-composition

Tried to use `(.)` for function composition, but it doesn't work.

```
import Data.String (length, trim)

trimmedLength :: String -> Int
trimmedLength = length . trim
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Function composition in PureScript is done with [`(<<<)`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/3.1.0/docs/Control.Semigroupoid#v:(%3C%3C%3C)), not `(.)`.

```
import Data.String (length, trim)

trimmedLength :: String -> Int
trimmedLength = length <<< trim
```

Comment: That's verbose. Doesn't puresript supports unicode and hence could have `∘`?

Comment: Yes, it's just not included in the core `Prelude`. Project-specific preludes will often define this if they're in unicode-friendly projects.

Comment: As of a couple of minutes ago, there's a library that (so far) does only this - [purescript-gorgeous](https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-gorgeous) - although it's not published on Pursuit yet.